# Storing #define macro value in temporary and re-use it

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to store a macro value into a temporary and reuse it. pseudo Example:

```
#define X 0

#ifdef X
#define T X
#undef X
#define X (T + 1) // now X should be 1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to achieve what you ask for.  Depending on what you want to do with that, the use of [`__COUNTER__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), a common extension, could help you.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it (this is an extension supported by GCC and MSVC) but not a standard one. I was interested in how to implement something like that using macros.